# Typescript: Create string type from Union of Array

Tags: javascript, typescript

Let's say that I have following type:

```
type ArrayType = ["AB"] | ["AB", "CD"] | ["X", "Y", "Z"];
```

I would like to transform it to the following type:

```
type TransformedArrayType = "AB" | "ABCD" | "XYZ";
```

How can I accomplish that in the Typescript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can join strings recursively using [template literal types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-1.html#template-literal-types):

```
type ArrayType = ["AB"] | ["AB", "CD"] | ["X", "Y", "Z"];

type JoinTuple<T> = T extends [infer Head, ...infer Rest]
  ? `${Head & string}${JoinTuple<Rest>}` : ''

type Test = JoinTuple<["AB", "CD"]> // "ABCD"

type TransformedArrayType = JoinTuple<ArrayType> // "AB" | "ABCD" | "XYZ"
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAggTnAhiAKuaBeKBtARDAIVwF0oAfHfIgGilwGEARE8ygDV1twE1O6AtEgG4AUCNCQoAKQD2ASwB2KAK5gANhAA8KAHxQsKKBAAewCAoAmAZxyKAZhDhQAEhEQXaAOm-3HUAEoQVsCkAPxQAAYAJADeru5QAGRQwXCKAOYAvrGyiirqWoHBOpkRUABcUADkVWIS0ChBwPrS8kqqGpp4hHwMzMR6APSDdIRMuHXoUChIClZ2MnAAthAW8EioU1i57QWa68hokEMjVLisVOMXbNyCQA)

Comment: Is there a way in TS to recursively iterate _heterogeneous_ unions without chained conditionals?

Comment: @jsejcksn could you provide specific example of what you're trying to do?

Comment: I don't have a case: it was just something I wondered in the moment. I think the answer is "no" because the serial conditionals are needed to discriminate and get to leaves.